# How to correctly implement a decorator interface to an overloaded class

Tags: typescript, types, decorator

I want to extend class `UserStore implements IUserStore` with a decorator, `@asyncStore`. `IUserStore` is an interface that extends `IAsyncStore`. TypeScript is however complaining that I'm not correctly implementing `AsyncStore` in class `UserStore`.

The full error:

```
TS2420: Class 'UserStore' incorrectly implements interface 'IUserStore'.
Property 'isLoading' is missing in type 'UserStore'
```

How do I correctly type everything so that my `UserStore` is correctly typed?

Here are some snippets of my code (left out irrelevant code and left interfaces empty if not related to this problem or error):

```
// Types
interface IAsyncStore {
  isLoading: boolean;
}

interface IUserStore extends IAsyncStore {}

// AsyncStore.ts
function asyncStore(constructor): any {
  class AsyncStore extends constructor implements IAsyncStore {
    private loading: boolean = false;

    public get isLoading(): boolean {
      return this.loading;
    }
  }

  return AsyncStore
}

// UserStore.ts
@asyncStore
class UserStore implements IUserStore {} // Error TS2420: ...
```

Comment: Decorators can't change the structure of the class. You can create a function that takes a class and returns an augmented class, but in your case, I think you should just make `AsyncStore` the base class for  `UserStore`

Comment: The question has been already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358687/how-to-correctly-implement-decorator-interface-to-overloaded-class . Deleting questions with proper answers instead of accepting them is not the best way to get help on SO. Also doesn't help other users who come to SO with same problem, if you care.

Comment: @estus It didn't answer my question, partly because the code example I gave was faulty, so I resubmitted my question.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm not looking to make it a base class. I want to use composition.

Comment: I just resubmitted it with almost no changes. It actually answers the question, this is how it's usually done. Consider providing feedback if you have problems with provided solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further googling, it looks like this is not supported by TypeScript yet. There is a little, but a bit dirty, workaround to get typings to work.

I added this class to my code:

```
class DecoratorService implements IAsyncStore {
  isLoading: boolean;
}
```

And then I use this class as a base class for `UserStore` like so:

```
class UserStore extends DecoratorService implements IUserStore {}
```

TypeScript no longer issues an error on my code, and I can run it without any errors. When I want to add another decorator, I simply add the necessary values to the DecoratorService class, and TypeScript will understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

Class decorator mutation [isn't supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) by TypeScript.

A class should be additionally typed with a merged interface in order to make added properties visible to the typing system:

```
interface UserStore extends IUserStore {}
@asyncStore
class UserStore /* implements IUserStore */ {...}
```

This conflicts with the purpose of using decorators for more concise code.

`implements IUserStore` is redundant, because it's guaranteed by `UserStore` merged interface that `UserStore` class already implements it.

Also, `IUserStore` doesn't serve a good purpose since it's same as the `UserStore` interface.

In this case direct inheritance is able to provide more trouble-free and consistent typing due to TypeScript restrictions.

Comment: `interface UserStore` is not a thing in my code or my example code. What is this in your example? I only have `IUserStore` and `IAsyncStore`. You mentioned this code before and it does not solve my issue.

Comment: It's merged interface. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html , It solves the issue. If you try this code, it should produce no type problems, at least in its current state.